# npm error 401 unauthorized with @scope/packagename.

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, npm-install

Trying to do `npm install` for a package fails when any of the dependencies have a scoped public package e.g. `@babel/generator` with a 401 Unauthorized
or something like

```
error Couldn't find package "@babel/generator" on the "npm" registry.
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case,
I tried an `npm logout` which might have cleared/reset local storage/session
info related to my npm login.
After that I am able to download/install publicly scoped packages normally.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Wes Bos here: https://twitter.com/wesbos/status/1067822624561143809

Logging into npm with `npm login` resolved this for me.